# parse hl7 with regex

Tags: regex, parsing, hl7

I have the following hl7 message:
  `MSH|^~\&|EPIC|SMHRMC|JCAPS|QHN|20170626165726|EDILABIH|ORU^R01^LAB|00004841|P|2.3|||||||||
PID|1||W00xxxxx^^^SMHRMC||mouse^Mickey^E||19860905|F||1|2601 somestreet AVE NO 8^^City^ST^zip^USA^^^county|MESA|(970)xxx-xxxx^P^PH|||Single||175375903|xxxxxxx||last^first^^|NON-HISPANIC||||||||||
PV1|1|I|MNEU^908^A^^R^^^^^^||||9999999^pcp^pcp^LYNNE^^^^^NPI^^^^NPI~999999999^last^first^LEE^^^^^NPI^^^^NPI||||||||||00000000^last^first^LYNNE^^^^^NPI^^^^NPI||000000603|CAID||||||||||||||||||||||||20170626000000`

Hl7 is hard to extract with regex however I have an field that is always in the same location and feel that might be easier.  I need to pull the encounter number which is the 'W00xxxxx' in the stream above.  It is always in the 3rd pipe delimited section of the PID and stops at the ^.

Currently I have:  select substring(column from 'PID\|[1]\|\|(.)\^') but this is not working.  However when I use select substring(column from 'PV1\|[1]\|(.)\|')  it will pull the 'I'.  I can't see the big differences in my regex to know why this isn't working.  Thanks.

Comment: A quick google shows many libraries for parsing HL7, why not use one of them?

Comment: Why are you sure it's even possible with regex? Most of practically useful languages are not [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

Comment: I am not sure it's possible, I'm just hopeful.  I am needing to extract via postgresql.  New to regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

```
PID\|[1]\|\|(.+?)\^
```

Comment: My next question, @t is if there is random text in the 2nd pipe delimited field, what would work.  Was looking at a non capturing group.  Example is: PID|1|anythinghere|W00xxxxx^^^SMHRMC||mouse^Mickey^E|

Comment: No, it wouldn't work. You'd have to add .*? between the 2 escaped pipe characters. This checks for zero or more of any character. PID\|[1]\|.*?\|(.+?)\^

Comment: Thank you, your comments are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably parse HL7 V2.x messages using regex because the encoding characters may change in MSH-1 and MSH-2. Whatever language you're using there's probably already an HL7 parsing library you can use instead.

Comment: I know this.  We have other methods, I just needed something fast and dirty for this one query.  Thanks,